# How can I include a JFreeChart servlet image in a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jfreechart

I have seen several examples of using a Servlet to dynamically generate a chart using JFreeChart, and subsequently including that image in a JSP using an img tag.  For example:

```
<img src="/MyChartServlet" width="400" height="300" border="0" alt="" />
```

My servlet which generates the image using JFreeChart works great, and I can see the image if I call it directly in the browser as in:

```
http:/myurl/MyChartServlet?id=274
```

The problem is that my JSP does not display the image.  In fact, the JSP is not even invoking the servlet.  I know this because I do not see the debug entries in the log that appear when the servlet is called.

In the Servlet I am using the JFreeChart `ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG()` method to write the image to the output stream of the response, because I do not want to write the image to disk.  As mentioned the servlet works fine when called directly.

What am I missing?  Or is there a better way to do this?  Maybe a plain old object can generate the chart and I can include that in the JSP?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about it the right way.  You may be having some kind of relative path issue from the context you're in.  Try

```
<img src="http://<full path to your servlet>" ...
```

Also, you have a ?id=274 in your example, but not in your img src.  If that's required, put that in there as well.

If you posted your servlet code, that could help, but also make sure you have your content type set properly in your servlet

```
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
```

Comment: I suspected it might be a path issue before posting this question, so I tried variations of the URL in the JSP to no avail.  It turned out to be a combination of path and the fact that I wasn't passing the ID directly to the URL.  I mistakenly thought that even if the ID was not set I would still see my debug statements in the log if the Servlet was invoked.  Not the case when trying to use the ID in the Servlet throws a NPE before writing to the log!  My solution was this in the JSP: <img src="./MyChartServlet?id=<%=id%>" width="400" height="300" border="0" alt="" />  Thanks for the assist!